# Identify a Horror film about bees which convert human into zombies

Tags: horror, identify-this-movie

I watched a horror movie approx 6 years before on TV about some kind of bee's which can turn human into Zombies by entering into their body mostly through their mouth or injuries .

Many people become zombies and tried to make more people like them.Its a Zombie Invasion type film but here human can easily tackle zombies but major problem is Bee's.

Near the ending of movie the group of people discover that music is the weakness of Bee's and they use it to fight them but somehow the bee's become immune to music and human looses the fight and only one girl remains in the end and which too attacked by bee's in the last seen.

I didn't remember the movie name and exact year of release. Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The movie you are looking for is probably [Infested](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0287497/). [Here is the trailer](http://www.reelz.com/trailer-clips/23712/infested-trailer/).

I have seen it and I remembered the song ("Da Da Da" by [Trio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trio_%28band%29)). It does not say anything about zombies in the description, but I think that this is the one.

It is not clear enough from the trailer that the people are zombified, but there are a few hints (see the ending scene, where the woman **lets** bees fly out of her mouth).